# Error: reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java

I am getting this error:

> Error: reached end of file while parsing

I know it means I need to close the curly bracket somewhere, but I have tried everything. I figured line 45 is the brace that needs to be closed, but I'm not sure how. This is a program for helping find the smallest number of coins needed to make the integer inputted by the user. For example, `37` would yield 2 Quarters, 1 Dime, and 2 pennies.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Change {
 public static void main(String[] args){

  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
Int n = sc.nextInt("Enter a positive integer" );
  int number1, number2; // Division operands
      int quotient;         // Result of division

 {if (QtrCnt > 0)

 if (QtrCnt > 1)
 System.out.println(QtrCnt + " quarters");
 else
 System.out.println(QtrCnt + " quarter");
}
if (DimeCnt > 0)
{
if (DimeCnt > 1)
System.out.println(DimeCnt + " dimes");
else
System.out.println(DimeCnt + " dime");
}
if (NicklCnt > 0)
{
if (NicklCnt > 1)
System.out.println(NicklCnt + " nickles");
else
System.out.println(NicklCnt + " nickle");
}
if (PennyCnt > 0);
{
if (PennyCnt > 1);
System.out.println(PennyCnt + " pennies");
System.out.println(PennyCnt + " penny");
}

int q = 25;
int d = 10;
int n = 5;
int p = 1;
if (a < 0);

System.out.println("ERROR");
{
 String (money >=25); { int numQuarters = money/ 25; }
 money -= numQuarters * 25;
 QtrCnt = (num1 - num1 % 25) / 25;
 num1 = num1 - QtrCnt * 25;

  String(money >=10); { int numDimes = money/ 10; }
 money -= numDimes * 10;
 DimeCnt = (num1 - num1 % 10) / 10;
num1 = num1 - DimeCnt * 10;

   String (money >=5); { int numNickles = money/ 5; }
  money -= numNickles * 5;
  NicklCnt = (num1 - num1 % 5) / 5;
num1 = num1 - NicklCnt * 5;

    String (money >=1); { int numPennies = money/ 1; }
  money -= numPennies * 1;
  PennyCnt = (num1 - num1 % 1) / 1;
num1 = num1 - PennyCnt * 1;
}
   }
```

Comment: You should format your code cleanly. This will make it VERY obvious where you are missing brackets. Also, you should *always* use brackets around `if` statement clauses to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are in fact missing the closing bracket for the class.

You also have a lot of brackets that basically don't do anything. Remember that if you don't put a { immediately after the () of an if, it won't belong to the if statement.

I cleaned up your code a little and got this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Change 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        Int n = sc.nextInt("Enter a positive integer" );
        int number1, number2; // Division operands
        int quotient;         // Result of division

        {   // <- Won't do anything
            if (QtrCnt > 0)
                if (QtrCnt > 1)
                    System.out.println(QtrCnt + " quarters");
                else
                    System.out.println(QtrCnt + " quarter");
        }

        if (DimeCnt > 0)
        {
            if (DimeCnt > 1)
                System.out.println(DimeCnt + " dimes");
            else
                System.out.println(DimeCnt + " dime");
        }

        if (NicklCnt > 0)
        {
            if (NicklCnt > 1)
                System.out.println(NicklCnt + " nickles");
            else
                System.out.println(NicklCnt + " nickle");
        }

        if (PennyCnt > 0);
        {
            if (PennyCnt > 1);
                System.out.println(PennyCnt + " pennies");
            System.out.println(PennyCnt + " penny");
        }

        int q = 25;
        int d = 10;
        int n = 5;
        int p = 1;

        if (a < 0);
            System.out.println("ERROR");

        { // <- Won't do anything
            String (money >=25); { int numQuarters = money/ 25; }
            money -= numQuarters * 25;
            QtrCnt = (num1 - num1 % 25) / 25;
            num1 = num1 - QtrCnt * 25;

            String(money >=10); { int numDimes = money/ 10; }
            money -= numDimes * 10;
            DimeCnt = (num1 - num1 % 10) / 10;
            num1 = num1 - DimeCnt * 10;

            String (money >=5); { int numNickles = money/ 5; }
            money -= numNickles * 5;
            NicklCnt = (num1 - num1 % 5) / 5;
            num1 = num1 - NicklCnt * 5;

            String (money >=1); { int numPennies = money/ 1; }
            money -= numPennies * 1;
            PennyCnt = (num1 - num1 % 1) / 1;
            num1 = num1 - PennyCnt * 1;
        }
   }
 // <- This is where you're missing the class bracket
```

Please try to improve the way you're formating your code because it really helps finding these kinds of mistakes very quickly.

Keep in mind that I only reformated the code, I did not change what it does or check if it even works.

Comment: When I add the bracket at the very bottom it says 59 errors.

Comment: That's because now that your class has an end point, the compiler actually has the opportunity to really check your code. Which seems to be full of errors ;)

Comment: Also when I try to remove the brackets you told me to remove it goes up to 86 errors.

Comment: First thing I'd look into is what on earth NicklCnt and PennyCnt and so on are and where you get those values because looking only at this code snippet I don't see where you ever defined them.

Comment: Im not sure aswell, this is my first ever code and I got some help and this is what I came up with.

Comment: As far as removing the Pointless ones is concerned: Are you making sure to remove the corresponding closing brackets as well?

Comment: If this is your very first code, maybe you should start with something a lot simpler. Try a basic tutorial or do a couple extremely easy exercises before you start doing something that involves this much code. I mean... I just looked at this code and I could probably walk you through all your compilation errors and at the end, the code still won't do what you want it to do because I honestly don't know what most of your code is even supposed to do. It just doesn't make sense to start with something like this if you've never written any code before.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean.